# My Polygon Fill Render Algorithm in SDL Have Weird Gradients

Tags: c++, sdl-2

I have created this function in SDL that draws to a texture which works kinda of as a canvas/plane for my geometry objects. It fills the polygons present in that canvas. It's based off the scanline algorithm https://www.educative.io/answers/what-is-scanline-fill-algorithm with a coloring method which name I don't know but I have the specifications, it's a college's work specification.

The vertices are drawn with their own specified color, this is done in another function and works well.
Edges are drawn with "incrementing ratios defined by (Color2-Color1)/(y2-y1) such as (red2-red1)/(y2-y1)" I'm doing this by adding this ratio to y_min distance to y (the redi, greeni... variables)
Inside vertices are drawn with incrementing ratio defined by (final color - initial color )/(final x - initial x)
Problem is, some colors look good, others get a weird effect which I suspect can be precision? SDL auto clamps if rgb goes below 0 or above 255 I believe. I get a lot of negative values on black colors.
Last Specifications:
The first and final pixel positions of a scanline are rounded in a specific way, before the "// Colors" commentary

```
// Scanline Algorithm
void scanline_fill()
{
    for (Polygon *polygon : polygons)
    {
        std::vector<Active_Edge> active_table;
        std::vector<Edge*> _temp_edges = polygon->edges;
        for (int y = polygon->y_min; y < polygon->y_max; y++)
        {
            // Interception
            for (int i = 0; i < _temp_edges.size(); i++)
            {
                if (y == _temp_edges[i]->y_min)
                {
                    active_table.push_back({(float)_temp_edges[i]->y_max, (float)_temp_edges[i]->x_y_min, _temp_edges[i]->m_inversed, _temp_edges[i]});
                    _temp_edges.erase(_temp_edges.begin() + i--);
                }
            }
            for (int i = 0; i < active_table.size(); i++)
            {
                // Remove y == y_max
                if (active_table[i].y_max == y)
                    active_table.erase(active_table.begin() + i--);
            }
            std::sort(active_table.begin(), active_table.end(), table_comparison);
            // Drawing
            for (int i = 0; i + 1 < active_table.size(); i += 2)
            {
                if (active_table[i].x_y_min != active_table[i + 1].x_y_min)
                {
                    int start = std::ceil(active_table[i].x_y_min);
                    int end;
                    if (active_table[i + 1].x_y_min - std::floor(active_table[i + 1].x_y_min) != 0)
                        end = std::floor(active_table[i + 1].x_y_min);
                    else
                        end = active_table[i + 1].x_y_min - 1;
                    // Colors
                    float ri = (float)(active_table[i].edge->a->color.r - active_table[i].edge->b->color.r) / (float)(active_table[i].edge->a->y - active_table[i].edge->b->y);
                    float gi = (float)(active_table[i].edge->a->color.g - active_table[i].edge->b->color.g) / (float)(active_table[i].edge->a->y - active_table[i].edge->b->y);
                    float bi = (float)(active_table[i].edge->a->color.b - active_table[i].edge->b->color.b) / (float)(active_table[i].edge->a->y - active_table[i].edge->b->y);
                    float rf = (float)(active_table[i + 1].edge->a->color.r - active_table[i + 1].edge->b->color.r) / (float)(active_table[i + 1].edge->a->y - active_table[i + 1].edge->b->y);
                    float gf = (float)(active_table[i + 1].edge->a->color.g - active_table[i + 1].edge->b->color.g) / (float)(active_table[i + 1].edge->a->y - active_table[i + 1].edge->b->y);
                    float bf = (float)(active_table[i + 1].edge->a->color.b - active_table[i + 1].edge->b->color.b) / (float)(active_table[i + 1].edge->a->y - active_table[i + 1].edge->b->y);
                    float redi = (float)active_table[i].edge->x_y_min_vertex->color.r + ri * (float)(y - active_table[i].edge->y_min);
                    float greeni = (float)active_table[i].edge->x_y_min_vertex->color.g + gi * (float)(y - active_table[i].edge->y_min);
                    float bluei = (float)active_table[i].edge->x_y_min_vertex->color.b + bi * (float)(y - active_table[i].edge->y_min);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, redi, greeni, bluei, 255);
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, start, y);
                    float redf = (float)active_table[i + 1].edge->x_y_min_vertex->color.r + rf * (float)(y - active_table[i + 1].edge->y_min);
                    float greenf = (float)active_table[i + 1].edge->x_y_min_vertex->color.g + gf * (float)(y - active_table[i + 1].edge->y_min);
                    float bluef = (float)active_table[i + 1].edge->x_y_min_vertex->color.b + bf * (float)(y - active_table[i + 1].edge->y_min);
                    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, rf, gf, bf, 255);
                    SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, end - 1, y);
                    float txr = (redf - redi) / (active_table[i].x_y_min - active_table[i + 1].x_y_min);
                    float txg = (greenf - greeni) / (active_table[i].x_y_min - active_table[i + 1].x_y_min);
                    float txb = (bluef - bluei) / (active_table[i].x_y_min - active_table[i + 1].x_y_min);
                    for (int x = start + 1; x < end - 1; x++)
                    {
                        SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(renderer, (float)(x - start + 1) * txr, (float)(x - start + 1) * txg, (float)(x - start + 1) * txb, 255);
                        SDL_RenderDrawPoint(renderer, x, y);
                    }
                }
                // Incrementing
                active_table[i].x_y_min = active_table[i].x_y_min + active_table[i].m_inversed;
                active_table[i + 1].x_y_min = active_table[i + 1].x_y_min + active_table[i + 1].m_inversed;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The complete version of the code and the classes can be found here https://github.com/Pfzoz/FillpolyAlgorithm

I suspect it's either precision or a logical error in one of the coloring specifications

Edit: (Images for visualization, top left is really off and all have non-smooth edges)
[image: Gradient Triangles]

Answer (score -1):

Major error was using the horizontal ratios alone, it's supposed to be the first vertex color plus the accumalating ratios (redi + txr)
Works

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).